# Django Integrity Error at /accounts/login/ 1364, "Field 'id' doesn't have a default value"

Tags: django, authentication, mysql-error-1364

I get the Django error when clicking on log in. Unfortunately I don't know which table is causing the problem.

My complete error:

IntegrityError at /accounts/login/

(1364, "Field 'id' doesn't have a default value")

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/
Django Version:     4.0.6
Exception Type:     IntegrityError
Exception Value:

(1364, "Field 'id' doesn't have a default value")

Exception Location:     c:\xampp\htdocs\django\ksfexpert\env\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py, line 254, in query
Python Executable:  c:\xampp\htdocs\django\ksfexpert\env\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version:     3.10.0
Python Path:

['C:\xampp\htdocs\django\ksfexpert\src',
'C:\Users\kit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python310.zip',
'C:\Users\kit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\DLLs',
'C:\Users\kit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib',
'C:\Users\kit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310',
'c:\xampp\htdocs\django\ksfexpert\env',
'c:\xampp\htdocs\django\ksfexpert\env\lib\site-packages']

Server time:    Mon, 26 Sep 2022 14:46:52 +0000
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

```
c:\xampp\htdocs\django\ksfexpert\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py, line 89, in _execute

                    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

     …
Local vars
c:\xampp\htdocs\django\ksfexpert\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py, line 75, in execute

                return self.cursor.execute(query, args)

     …
Local vars
c:\xampp\htdocs\django\ksfexpert\env\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py, line 206, in execute

            res = self._query(query)

     …
Local vars
c:\xampp\htdocs\django\ksfexpert\env\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py, line 319, in _query

            db.query(q)

     …
Local vars
c:\xampp\htdocs\django\ksfexpert\env\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py, line 254, in query

            _mysql.connection.query(self, query)

     …
Local vars
The above exception ((1364, "Field 'id' doesn't have a default value")) was the direct cause of the following exception:
c:\xampp\htdocs\django\ksfexpert\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py, line 55, in inner

                    response = get_response(request)

     …
Local vars
c:\xampp\htdocs\django\ksfexpert\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py, line 197, in _get_response

                    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

     …
Local vars
c:\xampp\htdocs\django\ksfexpert\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py, line 84, in view

                return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

     …
Local vars
c:\xampp\htdocs\django\ksfexpert\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py, line 46, in _wrapper

            return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)

     …
Local vars
c:\xampp\htdocs\django\ksfexpert\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\debug.py, line 92, in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper

                return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

     …
Local vars
c:\xampp\htdocs\django\ksfexpert\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py, line 46, in _wrapper

            return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)

     …
Local vars
c:\xampp\htdocs\django\ksfexpert\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py, line 133, in _wrapped_view

                        response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

     …
Local vars
c:\xampp\htdocs\django\ksfexpert\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py, line 46, in _wrapper

            return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)

     …
Local vars
c:\xampp\htdocs\django\ksfexpert\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py, line 62, in _wrapped_view_func

            response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

     …
Local vars
c:\xampp\htdocs\django\ksfexpert\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py, line 67, in dispatch

            return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

     …
Local vars
c:\xampp\htdocs\django\ksfexpert\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py, line 119, in dispatch

            return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

     …
Local vars
c:\xampp\htdocs\django\ksfexpert\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py, line 153, in post

                return self.form_valid(form)

     …
Local vars
c:\xampp\htdocs\django\ksfexpert\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py, line 98, in form_valid

            auth_login(self.request, form.get_user())

     …
Local vars
c:\xampp\htdocs\django\ksfexpert\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py, line 144, in login

        user_logged_in.send(sender=user.__class__, request=request, user=user)

     …
Local vars
c:\xampp\htdocs\django\ksfexpert\env\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py, line 176, in send

            return [

     …
Local vars
c:\xampp\htdocs\django\ksfexpert\env\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py, line 177, in <listcomp>

                (receiver, receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named))

     …
Local vars
C:\xampp\htdocs\django\ksfexpert\src\ksfexpertapp\models.py, line 995, in user_logged_in_callback

        UserAuditEntry.objects.create(action='user_logged_in', ip=ip, username=user.username, user_id=user.id)

     …
Local vars
c:\xampp\htdocs\django\ksfexpert\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py, line 85, in manager_method

                    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

     …
Local vars
c:\xampp\htdocs\django\ksfexpert\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py, line 514, in create

            obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)

     …
Local vars
c:\xampp\htdocs\django\ksfexpert\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py, line 806, in save

            self.save_base(

     …
Local vars
c:\xampp\htdocs\django\ksfexpert\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py, line 857, in save_base

                updated = self._save_table(

     …
Local vars
c:\xampp\htdocs\django\ksfexpert\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py, line 1000, in _save_table

                results = self._do_insert(

     …
Local vars
c:\xampp\htdocs\django\ksfexpert\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py, line 1041, in _do_insert

            return manager._insert(

     …
Local vars
c:\xampp\htdocs\django\ksfexpert\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py, line 85, in manager_method

                    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

     …
Local vars
c:\xampp\htdocs\django\ksfexpert\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py, line 1434, in _insert

            return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)

     …
Local vars
c:\xampp\htdocs\django\ksfexpert\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py, line 1621, in execute_sql

                    cursor.execute(sql, params)

     …
Local vars
c:\xampp\htdocs\django\ksfexpert\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py, line 103, in execute

                return super().execute(sql, params)

     …
Local vars
c:\xampp\htdocs\django\ksfexpert\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py, line 67, in execute

            return self._execute_with_wrappers(

     …
Local vars
c:\xampp\htdocs\django\ksfexpert\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py, line 80, in _execute_with_wrappers

            return executor(sql, params, many, context)

     …
Local vars
c:\xampp\htdocs\django\ksfexpert\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py, line 84, in _execute

            with self.db.wrap_database_errors:

     …
Local vars
c:\xampp\htdocs\django\ksfexpert\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py, line 91, in __exit__

                    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value

     …
Local vars
c:\xampp\htdocs\django\ksfexpert\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py, line 89, in _execute

                    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

     …
Local vars
c:\xampp\htdocs\django\ksfexpert\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py, line 75, in execute

                return self.cursor.execute(query, args)

     …
Local vars
c:\xampp\htdocs\django\ksfexpert\env\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py, line 206, in execute

            res = self._query(query)

     …
Local vars
c:\xampp\htdocs\django\ksfexpert\env\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py, line 319, in _query

            db.query(q)

     …
Local vars
c:\xampp\htdocs\django\ksfexpert\env\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py, line 254, in query

            _mysql.connection.query(self, query)

     …
Local vars
```

Unfortunately I cannot share the complete Model ... because it has about 13.000 lines

Comment: add ur complete error

Comment: Share your model, view and url....

Comment: Difficult without seeing the model. However, can you recreate the database?

Comment: please format your question for improved readability

Comment: As to see in my Answer, I found the error. In the table userauditentry the id was not unique

Answer (score -1):

Now I found the error. In the table userauditentry the id was not unique - why ever